# Nextjs : Where to perform some initialization operations on the server?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I want to do some operations after the service starts, such as logging tool settings.

Next.config.js is a good place, but currently my initialization logic is typexcript written.
Is there a solution for such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't gonna edit it often, you could just compile it yourself (manually with https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript for example)

Otherwise, you can find other answers here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5318

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the kind of logic you are trying to perform.

If you want to init your logging tool, it can be done automatically by importing your logging code logic. Example on Next Doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#logging

If you want to log some information during the server initialization, you should consider creating your custom server: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server